# External js libraries like datatable/jquery not recognized by nodejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs file like this:

```
import projectM from '@projectM/sdk-js';

var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

async function main() {
  //Some codes here
  $("#table_content").DataTable({
    aaSorting: [],
    responsive: true,

    columnDefs: [
      {
        responsivePriority: 1,
        targets: 0
      },
      {
        responsivePriority: 2,
        targets: -1
      }
    ]
  });

}
main();
```

In order to compile the project, I do:

```
npm run build
```

And then, `dist/index.js` is generated.

I include it in an HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./dist/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I call Datatable function inside index.js, it is not recongized and I get this error message:

```
TypeError: s(...).DataTable is not a function
```

Is there a way to include datatable js file inside index.js file (nodejs) directly ?

If not, is there a way to solve this problem please ?

Notice that I have many other JS file required for the HTML page and can't be installed from NPM just like I did for bootstrap and jquery, by the way ... any tricks to use directly external libraries for them aswell without installing them using NPM ?

Build script is: `webpack`

Thank you

Comment: Change `var $ = require('jquery');` to `window.$ = require('jquery')`, otherwise jquery will only work inside the file you declared `var $`.

Comment: jQuery works well ... the problem is the Datatable function that is included from the HTML file. It is not recognized from inside the index.js (nodejs) file. Check the error please.

Comment: Try to install datatables via npm: https://datatables.net/download/npm

Comment: I want use external js (It is a modified version) since there is much more libraries coming with it :) Thanks for your help.